# Understanding the basic naming scheme of the Android source code repository

Tags: repository, android-source, repository-design

I just downloaded the full 4.0.1_r1 Android Source Code repository according to the [official instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).  Can someone help me understand the repository's basic naming scheme?

For example, in the root directory of the repository, what exactly is the "frameworks" directory?  How does this differ from the "packages" directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have spend quite a bit of time around the android source code the last few years, so let me take a shot at explaining the different folders in the root. These are roughly (depending a bit on the android version):

- **bionic**

  - The standard c library used and developed for Android specifically.
- **bootable**

  - Contains the bootloader (which the device manufacture normally provides) and the recovery application which is execute when the phone is booted into recovery mode.
- **build**

  - Android has very unique modular build system, which itself is built on top of ordinary make-files. For example in `build/target/products` you will find all the generic build targets you see when you launch `lunch`.
- **cts**

  - [Compatibility Test Suite](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html). When a device manufactures wants to get their device certified (and thus get Google Play and other proprietary apps) they need to pass the CTS. The source of CTS is contained in this directory.
- **dalvik**

  - [The dalvik virtual machine](http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/). Android uses java for the better part of the framework as well as for all the apps. Because each app runs as its own process under its own uid, in its own virtual machine, the virtual machine have to have a rather small memory footprint, so Android have chosen to use a custom virtual machine for Java called dalvik. The source of dalvik is placed here.
- **development**

  - I haven't used this repository really, but it seems supporting stuff for developing android apps are placed here.
- **device**

  - Each device vendor put all the stuff that defines their specific devices here. For example you can provide a `devices/{yourname}/products/{yourdevice}.mk` defining exactly which apps should be build for your device (as well as a few other things). This adds an entry to the lunch menu called `{yourdevice}` that you can build.
- **docs**

  - As far as I understand this is actually the source of `http://source.android.com`.
- **external**

  - Almost all of the third party projects that Android pull in and which makes up the base Android Linux OS are located here. They are maintained in their own git repositories, which makes it easy to pull new versions from upstream. You see things like `bzip2`, `dbus`, `ping`, `tcpdump`, and many other projects here.
- **frameworks**

  - This is the source of the Android framework. All the stuff that you use when you build an app for Android. I think it is somewhere around 50% Java code and 50% C++ (and sometimes C), which is bound together using [jni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). When you for example play some audio in an app, you are probably accessing `AudioManager`. The source of `AudioManager` as well as all the internal Android source supporting `AudioManager` is placed under `frameworks/base/media`. You will find the bulk of the Android SDK implemented somewhere under `frameworks/base/`.
- **hardware**

  - Android talks to a set of libraries which then controls the hardware (such as vibrator, lights, proximity sensor, gps, audio, etc.). These libraries are collectively called the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer). Some default implementations are contained in the `hardware` folder, however manufactures implement their own libraries and place them in `hardware/{manufcaturename}` (or in `device/{manufacture}`).
- **libcore**

  - I don't know about this one.
- **ndk**

  - The [native development kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) which allows app developers to code some (or all) of their apps as native code (in c and c++ usually). Basically it is a toolchain to crosscompile to the different cpu architectures Android runs on.
- **out**

  - *All* Android build artifacts are placed here. So removing the `out` folder will clean the sources completely. `out` is divided into different folders, the main ones are `host` and `target` where stuff compiled for the host machine (e.g. adb) and for the target device (most of the android system) are separated. There are further subdivisions below, and in general the `out` folder is quite nicely sorted, so you should just explore it a bit yourself.
- **packages**

  - These contains all the default apps, providers, inputmethods, and so on, that are built along with Android. The phone app, contacts, calender, calculator, default soft-keyboard, etc, are placed here. They are not 3rd party apps, they are internal apps where many of them are build against non-public android apis. So most of the apps here cannot build against the public Android SDK (e.g. in eclipse), but have to be build as part of the complete Android build process.
- **prebuilt**

  - Stuff that is distributed along with Android as binaries. The primary thing located here are the crosscompiler(s) for building Android for ARM (and now also x86). They are prebuilt such that you do not have to actually build the crosscompilers yourself. (This could be very time-consuming if you besides Android also had to compile the crosscompilers.)
- **sdk**

  - All the tools that are part of the Android SDK, such as ddms, the emulator, sdkmanager, etc.
- **system**

  - The core system processes running on an android device. These are native (c or c++) programs. Mediaservice is an example of such a system service.

This is all from my experience with working with the Android source, I do not have any (other) references. I hope this helps you get an overview of the folder structure.